# Using infinite scroll AJAX load more with URL search parameter

Tags: ajax, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I have an infinite scroll working on my site. It works perfectly well on category pages, e.g.

> example.com/example

However, it doesn't work when I try to use it on a search page, e.g.

> example.com/example//?search=true&gender=female

I know I need to pass more `parameters to the AJAX call`, I'm just not sure how. The shortcode is like so...

```
do_shortcode('[talent taxonomy="'.$_GET['params']['taxonomy'].'" term="'.$_GET['params']['term'].'" page="'.$_GET['params']['page'].'" per_page="'.$_GET['params']['per_page'].'"]');
```

And the AJAX data:

```
var ajax_data = { 
    page:1,
    taxonomy:"'.$a['taxonomy'].'",
    term:"'.$a['term'].'",
    per_page:"'.$a['per_page'].'",
    max_pages: '.$my_query->max_num_pages.'
};
```

UPDATE: Here's the talent function called in functions.php:

```
function talent_func( $atts ) {

$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'term' => false,
    'taxonomy' => false,
    'per_page' => 4,
    'page' => 1,
    'gender' => 1,
    'orderby' => 1,
), $atts );
```

Here is the AJAX:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        'action':'talent_ajax',
        'params': ajax_data,
        'option':orderby
    },
```

Comment: How you are using this shortcode `[talent]` - via your custom function or a plugin?

Comment: hi ive updated the question to show the code for the talent shortcode

Comment: Seems to be partial, can you add the full `talent_func()` here? Also, is 'gender' your search keyword?

Comment: sorry will update again, no the gender at the moment isnt used in the ajax call and neither is the search parameter

Comment: If possible, paste full codes of your AJAX, template & `talent_func()` here - so it will be easy to check.

Comment: ive added the ajax script too now, but there is so much code im trying to keep it to a minimum, is that more helpful?

Comment: Okay, what is 'gender' here? Are you using default WordPress search ('s' as keyword)?

Comment: I think the old dev left that in there, it shouldnt be needed. search is keyowrd i think if you notice the url: example.com/example//?search=true&gender=female

Comment: Seems 'search' is not a keyword since you are passing 'true'. Can I know your search keyword?

Comment: cant seem to get here: http://phadev.wpengine.com/models/main-board/?search=true&gender=female# using echo get_search_query();

Comment: Are you referring 'FEMALES', 'MALES' as search here?

Comment: What is this female and male parameters? You should explain somewhat briefly

Comment: @user43251 Can you please provide a link if it is live? It would be easy to understand the exact cause.